# Why are unsatisfied dependencies not causing any errors?

Tags: typo3, extbase

In our code, we have a dependency defined like:

```
/**
 * @var \Vendor\Foo\Service\LoggingService
 * @inject
 */
 protected $loggingService;
```

When our code runs, at some point in the class, we try to access `$this->loggingService->foo()` and get the good old **Call to a member function on a non-object** error message.

Why is there no sooner indication of a problem coming from Extbase? Shouldn't the inability to satisfy a dependency cause some kind of error?

Comment: Don't know answer _why?_ anyway solution for this __Call to a member__ is clearing the whole cache as usually.

Comment: @biesior Been there, doesn't help. My point is, there could be a typo in the namespace or the class was defined in a different one, I would expect *some* kind of message to indicate a problem, instead of blindly running the code with unmet dependencies. So I somewhat assumed that there is some way to enable additional error messages.

Comment: @Olivier, agree it could be one, anyway AFAIK _blind testing_ is only option now (note: i didn't even search for this, usually cache clearing + error log check helps to find the TYPO in first approach for me)

Comment: BTW, I assume that `$loggingService->foo()` is just a typo in your sample, of course it should be `$this->loggingService->foo()` ?

Comment: @biesior Right, I just made that up. The actual source is syntactically correct.

Comment: Seems like there is an `UnresolvedDependenciesException`, but it is never actually thrown anywhere in the code :P